# No data from gyroscope sensor

Tags: sensors, gyroscope

here is a code that reads data from accelerometer sensor and gyroscope sensor. I have tested this application on many android devices like, samsung galaxy tab 2 or samsung dues or sky models...but non of them showed me the gyroscope data.
I'm sure the code is ok because all of the devices showed me the acceleration data but no data for gyroscopes.
can anyone help me? I know these devices have gyroscope sensors. then why non of them gives me the data?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener{

Sensor gyroscope;
Sensor acceleration;
SensorManager sm;
TextView gyro_text;
TextView acceleration_text; 

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    sm = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);

    gyroscope = sm.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE);
    sm.registerListener(this, gyroscope, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    gyro_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.gyro);

    acceleration = sm.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
    sm.registerListener(this, acceleration, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    acceleration_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.acceleration);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch(event.sensor.getType()){
    case Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER:
        acceleration_text.setText("X acc:  "+event.values[0]+
                                "\tY acc:  "+event.values[1]+
                                "\tZ acc:  "+event.values[2]);
        break;
    case Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE:
        gyro_text.setText("X gyro:  "+event.values[0]+
                        "\tY gyro:  "+event.values[1]+
                        "\tZ gyro:  "+event.values[2]);
    }
}

@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

May be you have similar issue as [this](https://www.ifixit.com/Answers/View/205752/Accelerometer+and+Magnetic+Sensors+stoped+working)

You may check if the sensor is supported (even if its present it may not be accessible to the app)

Use something like this:

boolean isAccelerometerSupported = sensorManager.registerListener(this, accelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);

boolean isGyroSupported = sensorManager.registerListener(this, gyroscope, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);

Although I myself am struggling to get values from accelerometer and gyroscope for Samsung devices (grand prime and S6). I am getting all 0 values with similar code as yours.

But the same code is giving non-zero values for Moto g2 device. So I suspect handling for samsung devices is different. Also, I will be looking for the solution and will let you know if I find something.

Refer to the android documentation for more information: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEvent.html